# How to Duplicate Array elements

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array which contains again arrays. Now I would like to have every inside-array twice in my main-array.

Unfortunately when going the way I did, I messed the index up and haven't been able to modify a specific element in the array (example: `Payliketable[2][5]`) because this is then there serval times.

How can I duplicate every inside-array while giving each it's own "index"?

```
i = 1
while i < len(PaylikeTable):
        PaylikeTable.insert(i,PaylikeTable[i])
        i += 2
```

As said the array "Payliketable" again consists out of arrays.

Comment: What does `PaylikeTable.shape` give you?

Comment: @yatu When I add this, I immediately get the error "instance of list has no shape member"

Comment: What is inside-array ? Can you provide an example of Payliketable @scenatic

Comment: Are they numpy arrays or simple lists?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to duplicate every element in an array ?
   For that just add array with same array

```
   list1=[[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]
   list1+list1 will get
   [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way, there is still the problem, that in the "doubled_list" do have the duplicates the same index. For example if I modify doubled_list[3][5] then it hit's both duplicates

Answer (score 0):

First off, never modify a list while iterating it. There should be better ways to do it.

To understand what I explained, check the current list after each iteration manually with a digestible starting list like `[[1], [2], [3]]`. You would easily see what is going wrong.

Assuming there are no memory constraints its better to make one more list:

```
doubled_list = []
for item in single_list:
    doubled_list.extend([list(item), list(item)])
```

using `list()` creates a copy of `item`, using `item` directly will refer to the same `item` instance.

More reading: [Copying a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Unfortunately this way, there is still the problem, that in the "doubled_list" do have the duplicates the same index. For example if I modify doubled_list[3][5] then it hit's both duplicates

Comment: Correct, I did not understand you requirement. I've edited with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutables. See here for more info about [mutables and immutables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types).

To create a copy of a mutable (and not just a reference to it), the best way is to use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) module.

```
import copy

PaylikeTable = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [5, 6, 2]]

i = 0
lpt = len(PaylikeTable)*2
while i < lpt:
    PaylikeTable.insert(i, copy.deepcopy(PaylikeTable[i]))
    i += 2

print(PaylikeTable) #the doubled list
#[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [5, 6, 2], [5, 6, 2]]

PaylikeTable[3][1] = 99

print(PaylikeTable) #only element 3, 1 is edited.
#[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [2, 99, 6], [5, 6, 2], [5, 6, 2]]
```